# How can I Integrate AOL in iPhone Application Through XMPP

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xmpp

I am developing chat application in that i included gmail,facebook chat,now i want to integrate AOL chat along those two.What is AOL server name for XMPP? I tried with "xmpp.oscar.aol.com" as AOL server name for XMPP, but xmppstream didn't connect.how can i integrate AOL in iPhone application throught XMPP.can any one help me.thanks inadvances

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple [XMPP client](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) written in ObjectiveC which you can directly use in your iPhone App.

Also `xmpp.oscar.aol.com` seems to be a test jabber xmpp server setup in 2008. Might not be up now. [from here](http://slashdot.org/story/08/01/18/1748218/aol-adopting-jabber-xmpp).